# GemFire value change without refreshing all values

Tags: gemfire, geode

I m using (String, Arraylist of String) as the key value pair in gemfire caching.Is there any method to just add or delete a particular value from the value list without getting the entire list and add/delete and publishing the list again?!

Comment: are you looking to do something like `get(key).add(new value)`?

Comment: Yea! N the whole key gets refreshed at the consumer end!

Answer (score 3):

You can create wrapper object to keep list. This wrapper object can implement [delta interface](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#developing/delta_propagation/implementing_delta_propagation.html). Using this you can add/delete field from list. See if this helps.

Comment: Thanks hitesh! But will it not refresh entire key at the consumer end if I add/ delete and will only send the updates to the consumer?!

Answer (score 0):

GemFire serializes the value when storing, and has various complex configurations to control the type and level of serialization.

Therefore, when you're updating a value in the value, what's happening is that the serialized value is being streamed to the client and then you're changing it and then re-serializing the changed value and streaming it to the server which is then storing it.

If you want to just update a value in the ArrayList on the server side itself, then you have to create a server-side listener and add that class to the server's classpath so you can manage the serialization/deserialization more finely.

Alternatively, you probably need to change your data model so that the ArrayList value is more like a Map, and is flattened to a secondary region colocated with the primary region, etc.